# ios XMPP Framework: How to give moderator role to users

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, asmack

I am using XMPP server for chat app.

I can able to login and create the MUC Room. But how to give Moderator role to Users, when users joined in my room.

I have used following code. But the role has not changed.

```
[room editRoomPrivileges:@[[XMPPRoom itemWithRole:@"moderator" jid:jidVal]]];
```

The debug log as follows

```
<iq type="set" to="myroomname@muc.blabla.com" id="C369C53B-1D1B-46D0-831F-847E74DCF0C5">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin">
        <item role="moderator" jid="11@gmail.com"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

Can anyone help me on this.